# Reuse UITableViewCell's without data repetition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I'm having some problem with multiple custom `UITableViewCell` reuse. I have 3 types of custom `UITableViewCell`. I tried to reuse the `UITableViewCell` using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

I wrote the `prepareForReuse` and made all possible subviews data nil. But still I was getting some repetitions of data in some `UITableViewCell`'s. So I was thinking of reusing just the xib without any data.

I made up the following code. The app seems to have some freezing problem now. Somebody please show me the correct way to reuse tableview `UITableViewCells` without data repetition.

```
 static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SystemListCell";

 IXSystemMessageCustomCell *cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXSystemMessageCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
      cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 }
 IXSystemMessageCustomCell *cellToSave = cell;
 [self configureSystemCell: cellToSave atIndexPath:indexPath];
 return cellToSave;
```

Comment: Did you mean that you are having 3 types of cells and they are appearing not as you need?or only the data within the cell are repeating?

Comment: Data within the cell are repeating. Please note that I'm using xibs to make the custom cells.

Comment: you have to use different identifiers if you have 3 different cells layout wise.

Comment: FYI and as an aside, you don't need to check for cell == nil anymore, although a lot of documentation still mentions that.

Comment: can you add the code that you are using to add the contents to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify the data in `prepareForReuse`

A better way is to

```
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath
```

We should always modify the data in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as this helps in reuse of cells.

Also, since you have created `IXSystemMessageCustomCell` class it is better to use this :

```
[[IXSystemMessageCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]
```

and write the setup code in `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

instead of this:

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IXSystemMessageCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 different reuse identifier for your 3 cell types:

```
IXSystemMessageCustomCell *cell;
if (some condintion) {
    cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"CellReuseIdentifierType1"];
} else if (some condition 2) {
    cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"CellReuseIdentifierType2"];
} else {
    cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"CellReuseIdentifierType3"];
}
```

In this case you don't need to re-configure cell each time for each cell type

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
IXSystemMessageCustomCell *cell = nil;
cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

By setting your cell to nil first, you are clearing out previous data associated with the reused cell.

Also register your nib once in your `viewDidLoad` or similar table view lifecycle method, so that this is not required at every call to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

So extract your static call from any method to be a private declaration...

```
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"SystemListCell";
```

and adjust your methods to read...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"IXSystemMessageCustomCell" bundle:nil];
    [<<self.tableView>> registerNib:nib
             forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    << ... other code ... >>

}
```

and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    IXSystemMessageCustomCell *cell = nil;

    cell = (IXSystemMessageCustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    [self configureSystemCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```